# How to cache a TCP reverse proxy data transmission?

Tags: go, caching, tcp, proxy, reverse-proxy

I've accomplished implementing TCP reverse proxy in GoLang. But unfortunately couldn't come up with implementing caching to a TCP reverse proxy. Is it possible to do so, if yes, is there any resource out there? Is caching possible on a TCP (Transport Layer of Network)?

Here's the simple TCP reverse proxy in Golang.

```
package main

import (
    "io"
    "log"
    "net"
)

//Proxy struct
type Proxy struct {
    laddr, raddr *net.TCPAddr
    lconn, rconn io.ReadWriteCloser
    errorSignal  chan bool
}

// New Create a new Proxy instance.
func New(lconn *net.TCPConn, laddr, raddr *net.TCPAddr) *Proxy {
    return &Proxy{
        lconn:       lconn,
        laddr:       laddr,
        raddr:       raddr,
        errorSignal: make(chan bool),
    }
}

//TCPAddressResolver resolves an address and returns to a struct having ip and port.
func TCPAddressResolver(addr string) (tcpAddress *net.TCPAddr, err error) {
    tcpAddress, err = net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", addr)
    return
}
func main() {
    listenerAddress, err := TCPAddressResolver(":8080")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to resolve local address: %v", err)
    }

    remoteAddress, err := TCPAddressResolver(":3000")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to resolve remote address: %v", err)
    }

    listener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", listenerAddress)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to open local port to listen: %v", err)
    }

    log.Printf("Simple Proxy started on: %d and forwards to port %d", listenerAddress.Port, remoteAddress.Port)

    for {
        conn, err := listener.AcceptTCP()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatalf("Failed to accept connection: %v", err)
            continue
        }

        var p *Proxy
        // HTTP is a stateless protocol thus a proxy needs to reinitiate the new next incoming call (conn)
        // each time it finishes handling the previous one.
        p = New(conn, listenerAddress, remoteAddress)
        p.Start()
    }
}

//Start initiates transmission of data to and from the remote to client side.
func (p *Proxy) Start() {
    defer p.lconn.Close()

    var err error

    p.rconn, err = net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, p.raddr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Remote connection failure: %v", err)
    }

    defer p.rconn.Close()

    go p.CopySrcDst(p.lconn, p.rconn)
    go p.CopySrcDst(p.rconn, p.lconn)

    //Wait for everything to close -- This one blocks the routine.
    <-p.errorSignal
    log.Printf("Closing Start routine \n")
}

func (p *Proxy) err(err error) {
    if err != io.EOF {
        log.Printf("Warning: %v: Setting error signal to true", err)
    }
    p.errorSignal <- true
}

//CopySrcDst copies data from src to dest
func (p *Proxy) CopySrcDst(src, dst io.ReadWriteCloser) {
    buff := make([]byte, 1024)
    for {
        n, err := src.Read(buff)
        if err != nil {
            // Reading error.
            p.err(err)
            return
        }

        dataFromBuffer := buff[:n]

        n, err = dst.Write(dataFromBuffer)
        if err != nil {
            // Writing error.
            p.err(err)
            return
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Edit the question to explain what you want to cache and how items in the cache are identified.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Question changed now.

Comment: do you mean to implement connection re use ?

Comment: You can't cache arbitrary TCP data without knowing which protocol is being spoken, and if you do, you need to be able to identify messages or otherwise identifyable chunks of data, _and_ know how said protocol identifes messages, whether caching is relevant for given types of messages, for who and for how long you cache messages, and so on. So please explain what you want to cache, how you identify it and _why_ you want to cache it at this layer.

Comment: @mh-cbon The question might be confusing but yes, Basically; reusing what's been transferred across the proxy. More specifically the function named "CopySrcDst", I want to cache the data (data that I'm reading from src.Read) for future use, as the proxy needs it for future incoming requests.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking how to save data read from an io.Reader. That's different from caching.

The easiest approach is to [tee](https://godoc.org/io#TeeReader) the reader into a [buffer](https://godoc.org/bytes#Buffer).

While you are at it, you might as well use [io.Copy](https://godoc.org/io#Copy) instead of the similar code in the question. The code in the question does not handle the case when read returns n > 0 and a non-nil error.

Use an [error group](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sync/errgroup) to coordinate waiting for the goroutines and collecting error status.

```
var g errgroup.Group
var rbuf, lbuf bytes.Buffer

g.Go(func() error {
    _, err := io.Copy(lconn, io.TeeReader(p.rconn, &rbuf))
    return err
})
g.Go(func() error {
    _, err := io.Copy(rconn, io.TeeReader(p.lconn, &lbuf))
    return err
})
if err := g.Wait(); err != nil {
    // handle error
}
// rbuf and lbuf have the contents of the two streams.
```

The name of the programming language is "Go", not "Golang" or "GoLang".